# Cross Tab Query Required SQL 2000

Tags: sql, crosstab

I have already googled for this

```
  
 I have a Table with following structure in SQL 2000

 ID ContactName Designation
 1  A           CEO
 2  B           ABC
 3  C           DEF
 4  D           GHI
```

I need the Output as follows

```
ContactName1 Contactname2 ContactName3 ContactName4
 A CEO        B ABC         C DEF         D GHI
```

Any Suggestions ?

Comment: I beleive this is the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312861/pivot-using-sql-server-2000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It occurs to me that a lot of the examples are for cross tab queries involving aggregation, which yours does not appear to need. While I do not necessarily condone Dynamic SQL, the below should give you the results you want.

```
Create table #Contacts (id int)
Declare @ContactTypes int
Declare @CAD varchar(100)
Declare @I int
Declare @sql nvarchar(4000)
Set @i = 1
Select @ContactTypes =   
Sum(sub.Types) 
from ( Select Count(1) as Types from contacts
group by ContactName, Designation) as sub
Print @ContactTypes
While @i <= @ContactTypes
Begin
    set @sql = 'alter table #Contacts Add  ContactName' + 
    Cast(@I as varchar(10)) + ' varchar(100)'
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    Set @I = @i + 1
End
Insert into #Contacts (id) values (1)
Set @i = 1
Declare crsPivot  cursor 
for Select ContactName + ' ' + Designation
from contacts
open crsPivot
Fetch next from crsPivot into @CAD
While (@@Fetch_Status = 0)
Begin   
    Set @sql = 'Update  #Contacts  set ContactName' 
    + Cast(@I as varchar(10)) +' = ' + quotename(@CAD,'''')
    exec sp_executesql @sql
    Set @i = @i + 1
    Fetch next from crsPivot into @CAD
End
close crsPivot
Deallocate crsPivot
select * From #Contacts
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [PIVOTED Table](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172756.aspx)

Comment: I have my DataBase in SQL 2000

Comment: Wasn't that link SQL Server 2000 specific?

Comment: My Table Schema has varchar column and the example shown in the link has int columns.. can understand it

Comment: Is the list of designations fixed or is it arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

This should work with 2000 also  - wg. without PIVOT

http://www.sqlteam.com/item.asp?ItemID=2955

Answer (score 1):

Yet another SQL Cross Tab proc http://johnmacintyre.ca/codespct.asp