# SQL Server 2000 pivot without temporary tables?

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm trying to pivot some data in SQL Server 2000, but the user that runs the application only have read/write permissions.  I've looked the solutions posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312861/pivot-using-sql-server-2000), but all involving create/destroy temporary tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may be a bit confused as to what temporary tables are.

You should be able to create a temp table (in memory) within your SQL statement.  No extra permissions are necessary.

Comment: I believed that temporary tables are created in the TempDb database.