# SQL Server 2000 - How do I rotate the results of a join in the final results of a query?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2000

My database is quite complex so I've simplified my problem down to the tables below.

`TableA` and `TableB` are related by the `NameID` field in `TableB`. I am trying to create a SQL statement to produce the desired results. I'm understand JOINs and how they work but I can't fogure this out.

There will never be more than 2 items in `TableB` for each item in `TableA`. There could be less than 2 items.

This will be used on a SQL Server 2000 server.

TableA

```
ID | Name
---+-----
 1 | John
 2 | Jane
 3 | Bob
 4 | Doug
```

TableB

```
ID | NameID | Information
---+--------+------------
 1 |    1   | Apples
 2 |    1   | Apples
 3 |    2   | Pears
 4 |    2   | Grapes
 5 |    3   | Kiwi
```

Desired Result

```
ID | Name | InformationA | InformationB
---+------+--------------+-------------
 1 | John | Apples       | Apples
 2 | Jane | Pears        | Grapes
 3 | Bob  | Kiwi         | NULL
 4 | Doug | NULL         | NULL
```

Comment: "less than 2 items" includes zero? If so you want these shown?

Comment: I changed your sample data for TableB ID 5, NameID from 4 to 3.  This change matches the Desired Result.

Comment: @Martin - Yes there could be zero entries in TableB, the result sould include the row. I'll add the example above @bobs - thanks for the fix

Comment: In the event that you have 2 results do you care whether they go in the A or B column?

Comment: @Martin - Ideally the lower ID would be in the 1st column, but I would be happy with any ordering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Edited to give the preferred ordering for the two columns)

```
SELECT a.Id,
       a.Name,
       STUFF(MIN(STR(b.Id, 10) + b.Information), 1, 10, '') AS InformationA,
       CASE
         WHEN COUNT(b.Id) = 2 THEN STUFF(MAX(STR(b.Id, 10) +
                                   b.Information), 1, 10, '')
       END                                                  AS InformationB
FROM   TableA a
       LEFT JOIN TableB b
         ON a.Id = b.NameId
GROUP  BY a.Id,
          a.Name
```

Comment: Thanks, now to adapt this to my database :)

Answer (score -1):

I think what you need to do is a [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx). Take a look and see if that suits your needs.

Comment: I don't think PIVOT is available in SQL Server 2000.

Comment: This was introduced in SQL2005. (originally had 2008, whoops)

Comment: Ah, sorry. Here's a StackOverflow question with a reference to that problem, though: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312861/pivot-using-sql-server-2000. That question in turn references this: http://www.sqlteam.com/article/dynamic-cross-tabs-pivot-tables.