# Is PIVOT supported with compatibility_level 80?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have written a query using PIVOT function.The db is on client side. When i am running the query it throws an error,

```
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.
```

After this I ran these two queries,

```
SELECT @@version;
SELECT compatibility_level FROM sys.databases WHERE name = 'db_name';
```

The output is

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)
```

and

```
80
```

I am not a db expert, But what I guess is they are using SQL server 2008 with compatibility mode of SQL server 2000 i.e 80 .Let me know if I am wrong. I do not think the Client will agree to change the compatibility level. So Is there any way to run a PIVOT query?

Comment: Just use an alternative with `CASE ... WHEN ... THEN`. Google it, it is easy to do

Comment: please post your query to suggest an alternative way to write the same.. as there can be many ways to improve the query..

Comment: Refer to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312861/pivot-using-sql-server-2000). It has some suggestions. Alternatively raise the compatibility level to 90 (SQL Server 2005), PIVOT/UNPIVOT was introduced in SQL Server 2005.