# Group by non normalised Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

Using SQL Server 2000 - I have an old database, and it's not normalised.

It has a bunch of columns like

```
memId
c1
c2
c3
c4
c5
```

These columns contain a number sample here

```
123
10
20
0
40
0

123
0
20
0
40
5
```

What I want is to extract the data grouped by the memId and column name like this

would come out as

```
memId  col   total
123    c1    10
123    c2    40
123    c4    80
123    c5    5
```

where the number is a sum for the group

I figured I could pull each time and union them all together, but was wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: Its a SQL 2000 db and unpivot doesnt seem to be supported

Comment: People still use SQL2000?! My condolences...

Comment: Thank you for your kind thoughts, I did open with "I have an old database"

Comment: I'm not sure "old database" quite describes a product that came out 16 years ago and hasn't even been supported for almost a decade! But how about a manual pivot, something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312861/pivot-using-sql-server-2000

Comment: Im looking to take columns to rows not the other way

Comment: you don't need the unpivot command to unpivot....

Comment: There are plenty of ways to do it in a newer DBMS. In an older one, a union statement is probably your best option. Without applies (which I don't think exist in SQL2000) and `UNPIVOT`, your options are pretty limited.

Comment: It's not just that Sql Server 2000 is "old'. Far more concerning is that it's old enough to be **way** past end of life. It no longer gets any patches, even for critical security issues, and hasn't for some time now. Continuing to use it is highly irresponsible. Upgrading this server is job 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you want to `unpivot` your results.  One option for your database would be `union all`:

```
select memId, 'c1' as col, sum(c1) from yourtable group by memId, col
union all
select memId, 'c2' as col, sum(c2) from yourtable group by memId, col
union all
select memId, 'c3' as col, sum(c3) from yourtable group by memId, col
union all
select memId, 'c4' as col, sum(c4) from yourtable group by memId, col
union all
select memId, 'c5' as col, sum(c5) from yourtable group by memId, col
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8b57f7/3)

Comment: Yes I mentioned this in my question "I figured I could pull each time and union them all together"

Comment: @sgeddes actually, the GROUP BY logically occurs before the select statement, so the query fails.

Answer (score -1):

It seems I misunderstood your point, oops. You are migrating the information to another table?

> **But first, a note about my use of the term normalization**
>
> ```
> First Normal Form
>  - Eliminate repeating groups in individual tables.
>  - Create a separate table for each set of related data.
>  - Identify each set of related data with a primary key.
> ```
>
> So clearly I was wrong about the normalization. **Ouch.** Good thing
>   I'm still young, eh? :/

I spent some time reevaluating this (a fatal mistake, no?) and also what the limitations of `SQL Server 2000` are. I found a useful compilation of the SQL Server 2000 manual available on [redware - SQL SERVER Handbook](http://www.redware.com/handbooks/sql_server_handbook/sql_server_sql_syntax.html).

When it comes to table expressions...the only thing that appears was `subqueries`and `views`, though no true Ranking function is available (thankfully, you can create `Functions`).

While you *could* add a value through some kind of cursive, why?

- You are still going to be parsing the table at least *N* x #Columns to be unpivoted. No complicated pivot (which did not exist anyways) required.
- Instead of using any kind of expensive cursive, `SELECT` 'C1' is simple and easily modified to the rows.
- You want to concatenate the tables, so the simplest method still is the `UNION ALL`.
- You can run the GROUP BY once after concatenation. Simple and elegant.

**SOLUTION:**

```
SELECT memID
     , Col
     , SUM(C1) AS Count 
FROM (
      SELECT 'C1' AS [Col], memID, C1 FROM  #Test2
      UNION ALL SELECT 'C2' AS [Col], memID, C2 FROM #Test2
      UNION ALL SELECT 'C3' AS [Col], memID, C3 FROM #Test2
      UNION ALL SELECT 'C4' AS [Col], memID, C4 FROM #Test2
      UNION ALL SELECT 'C5' AS [Col], memID, C5 FROM #Test2 ) AS A
GROUP BY memID, Col
ORDER BY memID ASC, Col ASC
```

**Source Table:**

```
CREATE TABLE #Test2 (memID INT, C1 INT, C2 INT, C3 INT, C4 INT, C5 INT)
INSERT INTO #Test2 (memId, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5)
VALUES (123, 10, 20, 0, 40, 0)
     , (123, 0, 20, 0, 40, 5)
     , (122, 5, 20, 10, 15, 0)
     , (122, 5, 0, 0, 0, 60)
     , (155, 10, 0, 0, 10, 10)
     , (155, 0, 0, 0, 50, 50)
```

**Results:**

```
memID   Col Count
122     C1  10
122     C2  20
122     C3  10
122     C4  15
122     C5  60
123     C1  10
123     C2  40
123     C3  0
123     C4  80
123     C5  5
155     C1  10
155     C2  0
155     C3  0
155     C4  60
155     C5  60
```

So I think your initial idea was right on.
Cheers.

Comment: I already have the data in that format, I need it such that each column becomes a row as per the example I provided.

Comment: @DaleFraser see my updated response. Thanks for the feedback. Definitely do not want to insist on bad knowledge!