# Get data monthly wise in Sql query from single Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot-table

I need to retrieve `monthly wise quantity` sold from a table.

How can i fetch all monthly wise data from the same column.

```
SELECT  IH_ITEMNO, SUM(IH_QTY) as July
from tbl_item_history
where IH_DATE LIKE '2022-07%' 
and IH_ITEMNO like '%PG'  and IH_TYPE ='S'
group by IH_ITEMNO 
order By IH_ITEMNO asc
```

This query return only `July` data as the input parameter is `july`. How can I get all the `months data` without passing input parameter in `where` clause.
Note: - `IH_DATE`  holds all the values of months.

The output would like be `ITEMNO, July, Aug, Sep, Oct......`

Comment: This is called a crosstab. There are many explanations on how to do this but typically you would need to explicitly name the columns

Comment: Here's an example of one type of syntax that you can use https://stackoverflow.com/a/5799709/1690193

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a good example, so try this (you'll need to add the additional columns);

```
SELECT  IH_ITEMNO, 
SUM(IIF(IH_DATE LIKE '____-06%',IH_QTY,0)) as June,
SUM(IIF(IH_DATE LIKE '____-07%',IH_QTY,0)) as July,
SUM(IIF(IH_DATE LIKE '____-08%',IH_QTY,0)) as August,
SUM(IIF(IH_DATE LIKE '____-09%',IH_QTY,0)) as September
from tbl_item_history
where IH_DATE LIKE '2022%' 
and IH_ITEMNO like '%PG'  and IH_TYPE ='S'
group by IH_ITEMNO 
order By IH_ITEMNO asc
```

Also be careful of storing dates. What data type is `IH_DATE`?

#### Edit

Given that `IH_DATE` is data type date, it's best to avoid implicit casts (for reasons of performance and defensive programming)

The code below doesn't do any implicit casts and will probably be faster for a large table with an index on `IH_DATE`

```
SELECT  IH_ITEMNO, 
SUM(IIF(IH_DATE >= '2022-06-01' AND IH_DATE < '2022-07-01',IH_QTY,0)) as June,
SUM(IIF(IH_DATE >= '2022-07-01' AND IH_DATE < '2022-08-01',IH_QTY,0)) as July
from tbl_item_history
where IH_DATE >= '2022-01-01' AND IH_DATE < '2023-01-01'
and IH_ITEMNO like '%PG'  and IH_TYPE ='S'
group by IH_ITEMNO 
order By IH_ITEMNO asc
```

#### EDIT 2

Also be aware that there are many ways to do pivots. In your case the required ourput columns are known and fixed, so this makes it simpler.

There is also some newer pivot syntax [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) that you might want to use instead but I believe it's just syntactical sugar.

Comment: The data type is `Date` of column `IH_Date`. Brilliant! You are Champ! You Saves a lot of time.

Comment: Given that, the current code is not ideal for performance. I'll add another option.

Comment: `IIF(IH_DATE >= '2022-06-01' AND IH_DATE < '2022-07-01',` might be wiser in case it's actually a `datetime`

Comment: Yep good point there. I'll update accordingly